# Error al Convertir una cadena tipo JSON a Clase en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Estoy construyendo una Web Api en c# Donde en una de las operaciones devuelvo un string que serializo

de esta forma:

```
 public string  GetCliente()
        {
            string resultado = string.Empty;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = Engine.FuncionesDb.TableDataCliente();
            List<Cliente> Customer = new List<Cliente>();
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                return resultado;
            }
            else
            {
             Customer = SetListaCliente(dt);
             resultado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customer);
            }

            return resultado;
        }
```

Este metodo convierte el DataTable en una List

```
  private List<Cliente> SetListaCliente (DataTable dt)
    {
        List<Cliente> Customer = new List<Cliente>();
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            Cliente lineaCliente = new Cliente
            {
                Numero = Convert.ToInt32(r[0]),
                Id = r[1].ToString(),
                Nombre = r[2].ToString(),
                Edad = Convert.ToInt32(r[3]),
                Telefono = r[4].ToString(),
                Mail = r[5].ToString(),
                Saldo = Convert.ToDouble(r[6]),
                FechaCreacion = Convert.ToDateTime(r[7]),
                FechaCreacionUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(r[8]),
                FechaModificacion = Convert.ToDateTime(r[9]),
                FechaModificacionUtc = Convert.ToDateTime(r[10]),
                Proceso = Convert.ToInt32(r[11]),
                Usuario = r[12].ToString(),
                Estado = r[13].ToString(),
            };
            Customer.Add(lineaCliente);
        }
        return Customer;
    }
```

mi clase cliente

```
public class Cliente
    {
        public int Numero { get; set; }

        public string  Id { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public int Edad { get; set; }

        public string Telefono { get; set; }

        public string Mail { get; set; }

        public double  Saldo  { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaCreacionUtc { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }

        public DateTime FechaModificacionUtc { get; set; }

        public int Proceso { get; set; }

        public string Usuario { get; set; }

        public string Estado { get; set; }
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para en mi aplicacion cliente convertir nuevamente en una lista Cliente? Lo he hecho de varias formas y siempre me devuelve error.

No me deberia dar error

```
resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                List<Cliente> Customer = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Cliente>>(resultado);
```

Comment: No he usado mucho el `DataTable` pero me parece que estas serializando `DataTable` y lo quieres deseralizar con `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

## Edición Respuesta 2020-01-04

La respuesta dada se hizo respecto a la pregunta planteada, pero esta no contenía la informacion completa por lo que no se pudo responder a la informacion omitida.

Al parecer el error esta en que JSON devuelto por la URI que se consultaba enviadaba los campos tipo **fecha** del cliente en un formato no estandar

.NET y cualquier lenguaje que intente interpretar JSON solo usa el formato estadar para identificar fechas a menos que se especifique manualmente como interpretar las fechas (el como hacerlo depende de cada libreria)

- Formato de fecha para JSON segun estandar ISO 8601 `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ`
- Formato recibido `dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm`

por lo que la solucion a leer las fechas desde el formato recibido era crear un Custom Converter de Newtonsoft para especificar el formato de lectura

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom DateTime JSON serializer/deserializer
/// </summary>
public class CustomDateTimeConverter :  DateTimeConverterBase
{
    private const string DateFormat = "dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm";

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(DateFormat ));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null) return null;

        var value = reader.Value.ToString();
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, DateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result))
        {
            return result;
        }

        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

## Respuesta de 2018-08-07

Estas serializando bien el Datatable, pero tu problema está en comprender que pasa al serializar el Datatable

```
string jsonCliente = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
```

En este caso al serializar una tabla (que contiene una lista de filas) se genera un JSON con un Array de objetos con las propiedades de la tabla, ejemplo

```
[
  { columna1: 1, columna2: 2, columna3: 3},
  { columna1: 11, columna2: 12, columna3: 13 }
   /* ... */
]
```

Quizá en tu caso al buscar por el id, obtendrás un array vacío o con un solo objeto

Por tal razon tu codigo presenta un error al intentar Deserializar una lista en un objeto Cliente

```
jsonCliente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cliente> // ERROR con la estrutura
```

En vez de eso tienes que Deserializar a una lista en este caso List

```
jsonCliente = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>> // Serializacion de una lista
```

Despues de esto puedes usar jsonCliente.FirstOrDefault() para el objeto o hacer lo que requieran con la lista.

Comment: Me devuelve el mismo error

Comment: Qué. Mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una respuesta basada en el siguiente articulo:

[Custom DateTime deserialization with JSON.NET](https://blog.kulman.sk/custom-datetime-deserialization-with-json-net/)

El error se encontraba al deserializar las fechas, que usan un formato diferente a la del estandar ISO8601 `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` usada por JSON para fechas por defecto

1. Modifique mi clase

   ```
   public class Cliente
   {

           /* otras propiedades */

           [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
           public DateTime FechaCreacion { get; set; }

           [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
           public DateTime FechaCreacionUtc { get; set; }

           [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
           public DateTime FechaModificacion { get; set; }

           [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter))]
           public DateTime FechaModificacionUtc { get; set; }

           /* otras propiedades más */                
   }
   ```
2. Agregue essta nueva clase a mi codigo para usar el formato `dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm`.

   ```
       public class CustomDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
       {
           /// <summary>
           /// DateTime format
           /// </summary>
           private const string Format = "dd. MM. yyyy HH:mm";

           /// <summary>
           /// Writes value to JSON
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="writer">JSON writer</param>
           /// <param name="value">Value to be written</param>
           /// <param name="serializer">JSON serializer</param>
           public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
           {
               writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ToString(Format));
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Reads value from JSON
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="reader">JSON reader</param>
           /// <param name="objectType">Target type</param>
           /// <param name="existingValue">Existing value</param>
           /// <param name="serializer">JSON serialized</param>
           /// <returns>Deserialized DateTime</returns>
           public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
           {
               if (reader.Value == null)
               {
                   return null;
               }

               var s = reader.Value.ToString();
               DateTime result;
               if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, Format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
               {
                   return result;
               }

               return DateTime.Now;
           }
       }
   ```
3. Mi codigo

   ```
       private string  ClientGetRequest(string RequestURI)
       {
           string resultado = string.Empty;

           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50445/");
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
           HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
           response = client.GetAsync(RequestURI).Result;
           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               resultado = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               resultado = resultado.Replace("\\", "");
               resultado = resultado.Replace("/", "");
               resultado = resultado.Replace("\"[", "[");
               resultado = resultado.Replace("]\"", "]");
               string [] partes = resultado.Split(',');


               var resulta = resultado;
               List<Cliente> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cliente>>(resulta);

           }
           else
           {
               resultado  = response.IsSuccessStatusCode.ToString();
           }

           return resultado;
       }
   ```